# Python while loop with countdown and condition

Tags: python, while-loop

I need to create while loop with condition that gets response from another thread but not wait for it too long. That's why I decide to use two conditions like

```
i = 0
while (not is_get_responce() and i<10000):
    i+=1
    time.sleep(1)
```

Is it a good practice?

let's avoid XYproblem

I have two threads and shared storage for this threads, all I need is to wait from the second thread while first thread did his job, after that, I get the result from the first thread and put it to my second thread. For sharing the result of jobs I used shared storage and function `is_get_responce()` return boolean if we have a response from the first thread.

I know that I can use .join() to wait for the first thread but I don't have a link from the second thread for it and it's not a good option for my case.

Comment: What is the other thread like? How is `is_get_responce()` defined?

Comment: The other thread just uses shared storage and set flat to true or false
the function `is_get_responce()` just return bool `True` if we get a response from other thread another way I get `False`.

Comment: Okay. If the thread is responsible for only a single request-response cycle, whatever it is, you might want to just use the `.join()` method to wait for completion, as suggested by @Maël Pedretti.

Comment: I don't have a link to .join() thread inside another thread.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `is_get_responce()` correctly configured, something like the following would make more sense to me:

```
start = time.time()
while time.time() - start < 10000:
    if is_get_responce():
        break
    time.sleep(1)
```

---

That being said, this could actually be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is possible in your case but the best practice is the following.

Use [thread.join() method](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) and specify a timeout.

This allow you to wait for a thread to finish until the optional timeout occurs.